# How do I switch product images from magento 1 to magento 2?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2.3, product-images, media-images

I'm trying to migrate the images from Magento 1 to Magento 2, and I detected that the images are inside the media folder in both Magento versions, but when I get the `media/catalog/product` directory from Magento 1 and move to Magento 2, it comes with far fewer images than it should.

How can I switch product images from Magento 1 to Magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this process :

1. Go To this directory from magento1 :

> media/catalog/product

2. Now Do the zip file of all the images. (Either using Cpanel or from SSH, whatever feasible for you)
3. Now Move that Zip file from Magento1 to Magento 2 on this directory: `pub/media/catalog/product`
4. Now you can Unzip that file.
5. Run this commands one's `php bin/magento catalog:images:resize`

Answer (score 0):

php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
This command might run for hours depending on how many images you have.

The other way could be importing Magento products and in that specifying image names.
Then in import directly place all these images.

When products are imported then if images are in import location they too will be processsed.